# How to open multiple links in different windows using selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to open different subreddits using selenium, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to be able to open a specified number of subreddits, from a specified search term.

Usually, I would just put in the url, but I can't do that, because when the user inputs a different keyword, it would come up with different results. Here's the [example link](https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=aaa).

When I use inspect on the first 3 subreddits (the ones I want to click), I can't really see a real way to differentiate them, other than the subreddit name (can't use, as people will be using different search terms).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Using Visual Studio, C#, and selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can locate all such links present in page using a common locator and then click all of them one by one:

```
 IList<IWebElement> reditLinks= driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[text()='Communities and users']//following-sibling::div//a//div//div[contains(@class,'_2torGbn')]"));
// For current page, it will return list of 3 elements.
    for (WebElement reditLink: reditLinks){
    reditLinks.Click();
    }
```

Note : I am no expert in C#, I am more of a Java / Python person. But idea here will work.